# Pointers to members of members or an alternative?

Tags: c++, templates, c++03, pointer-to-member

Say I have a template function which sets data in a struct via pointers-to-member:

```
struct S
{
    double d;
    unsigned int u;
};

struct A
{
    S s, s2;
    float f;
    int i;
};

template<typename Stream, typename Class, typename Type>
void read(Stream& s, Class& out, Type Class::*member)
{
    s >> out.*member;
}
```

Now for regular members like `f` and `a` I can use this function on an arbitrary instance of `struct A`:

```
#include <sstream>

int main(int, char**)
{
    std::stringstream stream;

    A a;
    stream.clear(); stream.str("1");
    read(stream, a, &A::i);
    stream.clear(); stream.str("1.5");
    read(stream, a, &A::f);
    stream.clear(); stream.str("2");

    printf("%i\n", a.i);
    printf("%f\n", a.f);
}
```

But is there any way to access members of `A::s` or `A::s2` in a similar fashion *without* writing a new, effectively identical function for every composite member (`s`, `s2`, etc.)?
Pointers to members of members do not exist to my knowledge, but is there an alternative solution? (It has to work on arbitrary instances of a `struct` or `class`, similarly to how the pointer-to-member solution above works and should not require additional methods in `A` or `S`).

To clarify the question somewhat (see also the comments in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16928366/2361316)): In the real code (a config file reader), the caller does a lookup in a map with a first string and doesn't actually know what is currently being read (using the second string), as the pointer-to-member parameter is bound. Also the map is initialized once and used for multiple instances of `A`, therefore the pointers-to-members.

Please note the c++03 tag. Therefore c++11 lambdas are not an option.

Comment: There is no such member pointer. [What are you trying to do](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? This is an awfully weird way to populate a class.

Comment: @GManNickG added some clarification (and I already stated in the question itself that I know that there is no such pointer...)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I get the problem right. 
Just as you could reach members i, f with a PTM you can do the same with S. You don't need a separate funcition to access s and s2: a single function will do with an extra argument of type `S A::*`.

Or if the types must be variable, you can extend your read function something like:

```
template<typename Stream, typename Class, typename Type, typename Class2, typename Type2>
void read(Stream& s, Class& out, Type Class::*member, Type2 Class2::*member2)
{
    s >> ((out.*member).*member2);
}
```

and use it like `read(stream, a, &A::s, &S::u);`

(I don't have compiler at hand to test it, it may need some touch-up)

Comment: This is in probably the closest you can get to what I was looking for. You can save a template parameter though, as `Type` and `Class2` must be identical.